# Sending variables through an auto-submited FORM

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page like this:

```
<head>
<script>
function change(alfa) {
document.getElementById("vtp").innerHTML="<form id='send' method='post' action='page.php'><input type='text' name='alfa' value='"+alfa+"'></form>";
document.getElementById("send").submit(); }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<span id="vtp"></span>

*** PHP fragment
$alfa=$_POST["alfa"];  //this variable is used in showing the page
*** end PHP

<img src="image1.png" onclick="change('text1')">
<img src="image2.png" onclick="change('text2')">

</body>
```

The page is more complicated, but principially is like this.
The problem is very strange: the page works fine at first 3-4 calls (let's say 1 minut), but afterwards the server of the hoster crashes. I tried to upload this page on different servers (hosters), but all the servers have the same behaviour (after few seconds the connection get interrupted till I refresh my IP). I can't understand where I am wrong. Why it works the first 2-3 times, but aftewards the hoster denies my IP ? Am I infrige some security policies, or my code really has a problem ? It seems so strange for me.

**EDIT:**

This behaviour depends on browser: it exists in Chrome, but not in Explorer. In Explorer the page works ok (without any interruption). So, what does this mean ? What should I modify in the page to work well in Chrome too ? I really can't understand such a strange behaviour. Help me please (if you have any idea)!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use AJAX?

Comment: For my shame, I don't know AJAX. But, as far as I know, the (most of) mobile devices don't support/recognize AJAX. But maybe I'm wrong.